# Flyway and Liquibase call through webservices like Soap, Rest

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, liquibase, flyway

I have integrated both liquibase & flyway with my application. Both are working fine. Both have their pros & cons. Now my concern is with webservices. Can Rest and Soap be used with these tools. If yes then can you please elaborate in details???
   I need to use these tools with hudson and can Rest & Soap be used to call liquibase or flyway.  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a layered architecture with Remoting / Services / DataAccess layers

- Both Flyway and Liquibase sit at the DataAccess layer
- Both REST and SOAP sit at the Remoting Layer

Neither Flyway nor Liquibase impose restrictions on the kind of remoting technology being used.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase has a java interface primarily accessed through liquibase.Liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org/api/liquibase/Liquibase.html) which can be used to programatically perform liquibase operations.

There is not built-in support for rest or soap, but either can easily be created.

**UPDATE: Example code**

```
Connection c = createDatabaeConnection();
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(c));
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(changelog, resourceOpener, database);

liquibase.update(contexts)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathan
Can you briefly explain how can we use rest or soap with any of these two tools. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I assumed from your question, what you want to do is be able to have a soap or rest service you call which will perform the database updates.

For liquibase, that would mean creating a method that is called by whatever soap or rest framework you use that contains code similar to the code I added to my answer